# Resize Image and Text Together While Display Size Decreases

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have developed a website, now I have to make it responsive. I have almost done it, but the below div I cant do.

```
    <div class="menu-top-menu-container">
<ul class="topmenu" id="menu-top-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-37" id="menu-item-37">
        <a href="http://localhost/safesteps/why/">Why |</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-39" id="menu-item-39">
        <a href="http://localhost/safesteps/our-ambassador/">Our Ambassador |</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40" id="menu-item-40">
        <a href="http://localhost/safesteps/get-involved/">Get Involved |</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-38" id="menu-item-38">
        <a href="http://localhost/safesteps/partners/">Partners |</a>
    </li>
    <li class="youtube_menu menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-53" id="menu-item-53">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have applied CSS using media queries like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    ul.topmenu a{
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 4vw;
    }
    .youtube_menu{
        top:4px;
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

but this css is working for the texts,and it re-sizes when browser size decreases. but for the YouTube logo it remains the same.

please tell me how to resolve this.
[image: check the red marked area]

Comment: are you sure you want to use vm font-size unit for your website? that's a very new feature and 73% support is not very much: http://caniuse.com/#search=vm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change size of YouTube logo you should put it in *img* tag and then in tour CSS, change properties like *width* and *height*.

Or, if you want to keep it as a background image, then put it into *relative positioned* wrapper and apply *absolute positioning* to logo like [there](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).

Comment: but I can only hard-code the size right ? but then the size will remain as same when the display re-sizes again

Comment: You can use percentages. Percentage relative to the window size, or to the parent container.